# Is my request body secured if the request headers has header.payload.signature?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, web-services, webhooks

Is my request body secured if the request headers has header.payload.signature?

Webhooks sends the data in post method with request header and request body..the request headers are coming with the header.payload.signature  and the body in the normal Json structure. How secured is the request body to api?

Comment: can you provide some code ?

Comment: The request is in HTTPS or non-HTTPS ?